# Exporting location of ssh key pair

Tags: bash, shell, security

Is it safe to in include a $KEY="path/to/sshkey" in my bash profile file ?

It works I just want to make sure it is not a vulnerability.

Everything works with my workflow, just want to make sure that the git hub repository where I have my dot files does not become a vulnerability

Comment: The location of the file need not be secret.  Instead, ensure only the processes you expect to have access, have access.

Comment: "Safe" in what sense?

Comment: Note that there are other things that a `.bash_profile` might plausibly contain that could be equally or more sensitive than the key file location.  For example, if in it you add directories to your `PATH` then that provides information about software installed on your computer and its location.

Comment: At least it would make sense to do it syntactically correct: Drop the leading `$`. Also think whether you need it as shell variable or as environment variable.

Comment: Why do you need to store the path to a key in a variable? If you are trying to simplify commands like `ssh -i $KEY ...`, then I suggest configuring the key to use for a specific host in your `.ssh/config` file instead.

Answer (score 2):

> just want to make sure that the git hub repository where I have my dot files does not become a vulnerability

Anything that potentially gives an adversary information that they otherwise might not have had reduces security.  That includes

- recording the path to a private key in an environment variable
- putting a command to set such an environment variable in your `.bash_profile`, even if it were commented out or otherwise never executed
- putting a copy of the `.bash_profile` in a GitHub repository

  - even if the repository is private

How significant that is can vary, however, depending on how valuable and / or sensitive the information is, and how difficult it would be to access.

The location of a private key file is moderately sensitive.  The vector here is that knowing the location of the key could help an adversary obtain the key itself, and thereby elevate their privileges.  That risk would be mitigated -- but not eliminated -- by strong access controls on the file itself.

The difficulty of lifting the key file location directly from your `.bash_profile` would depend on a variety of factors.  It might not require the ability to assume your identity.  Having the keyfile location in the environment of all your shells provides more, and perhaps easier ways for an adversary to obtain it.  Having it in a public revision-control repository would make it completely unprotected.

This is complicated, which is why we have jobs for information security professionals (which I am not).  However, my informed layman's estimate is that the incremental risk of what you describe is low, supposing that you exercise good security practices generally: strong passwords, changed periodically; least permissive access controls feasible; strong encryption where appropriate; *etc*.